# how to check which database is used in dbt when running dbt run command?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Database 'ANALYTICS' does not exist or not authorized.
WHEN IM TRYING TO RUN dbt run i am facing the above error
[dbt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giEgk.png)

profile.yml

```
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: snowflake
      account: yg06501.ap-southeast-1

      # User/password auth
      user: jayakrishna
      password: *****8


      role: ACCOUNTADMIN
      database: JK_JSON_DB
      warehouse: transform_wh
      schema: public
      threads: 2 
      client_session_keep_alive: False
      

      # optional
      connect_retries: 3 # default 0
      connect_timeout: 10 # default: 10
      retry_on_database_errors: True  #default: true 
      retry_all: True  # default: true
```

dbt_project.yml

```
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'i_love_dbt'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'my-snowflake-dbt-db'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `source-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
source-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analysis"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
data-paths: ["data"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"  # directory which will store compiled SQL files
clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
    - "target"
    - "dbt_modules"
models:
  i_love_dbt:
      # Applies to all files under models/example/
      example:
          materialized: table
          vars:
            my_first_variable: True
            my_second_variable: 2020
            my_third_variable: 1
          pre-hook: "insert into dbt.audit (model, state, time) values ('{{this.name}}', 'starting model deployment', current_timestamp)"
```

To detect or rectify why I am facing another database name when I am trying different one.

Comment: Are you running dbt against MySQL or Snowflake? You've tagged both; your profile says Snowflake. Databases are entirely different things in Snowflake and MySQL!

Comment: IM USING SNOWFLAKE

Answer (score 0):

`ANALYTICS` is the default database name for dbt-snowflake, which would lead me to think that dbt can't find the profile you've defined. Some possible causes:

1. Your profiles file needs to have a top-level key that matches the profile name defined in your dbt_project.yml file. From that file, that name should be `my-snowflake-dbt-db`. So your profiles file should start with a key with that name:

   ```yaml
   my-snowflake-dbt-db:
     target: dev
     outputs:
       dev:
         type: snowflake
     ...
   ```
2. dbt expects the profiles file to be called `profiles.yml` (note the `s`), and it should be located at `~/.dbt/profiles.yml` on unix systems. For a different path, you can run dbt with the `--profiles-dir` option.

Finally, there is a command to help with all of this: `dbt debug`. That will run a check and tell you if it can find your profile, connect to your database, etc. [Docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/debug)

Comment: hi @tconbeer  thanks for helping ,i had done the exact thing created another user  and grant prilages to db and schema but i am getting another database  when i run dbt run.

Comment: what does it say when you do `dbt debug`?